# A* Pathfinding in Lua

Tags: lua, path-finding, a-star

I recently implemented A* pathfinding in Lua, but I am experiencing bad paths due to using the Manhattan method for the H in costs.

[image]

I would like to know if there are any other methods of calculating the cost of nodes. Here is what I am currently using:

```
function CalcG(A,B)
    if type(A) == "table" then
        A = A.Pos
    end
    if type(B) == "table" then
        B = B.Pos
    end
    return (A-B).Magnitude
end

function CalcH(A,B)
    if type(A) == "table" then
        A = A.Pos
    end
    if type(B) == "table" then
        B = B.Pos
    end
    return math.abs(A.X - B.X) + math.abs(A.Z - B.Z)
end

function GetCost(A,B,C)
    return CalcG(A,B) + CalcH(B,C)

end
```

And to calculate the cost:

```
GetCost(Start,CurrentNode,End)
```

If anybody could direct me towards a better heuristic method, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Using the Manhattan heuristic should not result in that path. I think you may have some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: What WuTangTan says in the comments still applies; this looks like a bug in your implementation as well)

A correct A* implementation is guaranteed to find the shortest path as long as the heuristic is **admissible**, or does not overestimate the actual cost of a path (see [Wikipedia's entry on A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) for more details). For a grid where you cannot move diagonally, Manhattan distance fulfills this criteria. But judging from your image, it looks like you are able to move diagonally as well, so Manhattan distance does not accurately judge distance anymore. Consider this picture:

[image: Example image]

Blue is Manhattan distance, green is the 'correct' distance.

As you can see, when we add the ability to move diagonally, the distance between the two points becomes shorter. Manhattan distance now overestimates the distance and is now not admissible, resulting in A* not always finding the shortest path.

So is there a heuristic that we can use to model diagonal grid movement? You bet! It's called **[Chebyshev distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)**. It takes into account diagonal movement, so it is much better for modeling distance in this scenario. Think of a King on a Chessboard.

Its implementation is simple:

```
function chebyshevDistance(dx, dy)
    return math.max(dx, dy)
end
```